# Why two router Emberjs error

Tags: ember.js

I have code emberjs router is below.I have two router `App.CateProductRoute`  and  `App.ProductRoute`

then
`console.log("CateProduct");` not run function  show console

`console.log("Product");` run function show console

---

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {

    //Product
    this.resource('cateproduct', function () {
        this.route('cateproduct', { path: 'cateproduct/:id' });
    });
    this.resource('product', function () {
        this.route('product', { path: 'product/:id' });
    });

})

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function () {
        return {};
    }

});

App.CateProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function () {

        console.log("CateProduct"); not is run show
    }

});

App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function () {

        console.log(" Product");  is run show

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ember` doesn't know that you want to *camelCase* your `CateProduct` Route and therefore instead of using your declared `CateProduct` Route, Ember is creating the missing Route --> `CateproductRoute`.

Conclusion: Rename your `CateProduct` Route (and all Controllers, Models, etc.) to `Cateproduct` or rename your `resource` to `cateProduct` (just rename the resource, the path can remain the same) and everything should work with `CateProduct` too :) - also, for this type of routing you won't need the inner routes - everything works without them pretty well

so, you either have:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('cateProduct', {path: 'cateproduct/:id'});
  this.resource('product', {path: 'product/:id'});
});
```

and keep your `CateProduct` named `Route/Controller/Model`

or you have:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('cateproduct', {path: 'cateproduct/:id'});
  this.resource('product', {path: 'product/:id'});
});
```

and rename your `Route/Controller/Model` to match `Cateproduct`

Comment: Thank you HEROM .I tested folow you post but two router is not run console.log() in CateProductRoute ,ProductRoute

Comment: I create a working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/neyadape/1/) example based on your code wth my suggestions, feel free to play with it ;)